# Issue to send form with ajaxForm function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send data included in form with ajaxForm Function. It works fine in localhost but when I try it on the internet it doesn't work and shows error.

this is my form header

```
<form id="form" role="form" action="controller/PagesManager.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

this is the include of the ajaxForm JS file

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

this is my AJAX function

```
function saveBonReception(){
    $('#form').ajaxForm({ 
        success: function(responseText, statusText) {
            if($.trim(responseText) == 'ok'){
                $(location).attr('href', 'index.php?p=BonReception&msg=true');
            }
        },
        error : function(b, msgError) {
            alert("Error Ajax : " + msgError);
        }

    }).submit();    
}
```

and this my traitement in PagesManager.php

```
if(!empty($_FILES['docFour'])){
        $brcPath = '../BRC_Files/';
        $brcFile = $_FILES['docFour']['name'];
        list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $brcFile);
        $nameFile = 'File_'.time().'.'.$ext;
        $tmp = $_FILES['docFour']['tmp_name'];
        $fileUploaded = move_uploaded_file($tmp, $brcPath.$nameFile);
        if(!$fileUploaded) die('notOk');
    }
    else {
        $nameFile = 'Aucun Fichier';
    }
    $bonReceptionEntity = new BonReceptionEntity();
    $bonReceptionManager = new BonReceptionManager();
    $bonReceptionEntity->setmagasinier(($_SESSION ['ADMIN_ID']));
    $bonReceptionEntity->setcode($_POST['codeBonReception']);
    $bonReceptionEntity->setdate(dateformat_jQueryUI_to_SQL($_POST['dateBrc']));
    $bonReceptionEntity->setdate_doc_four(dateformat_jQueryUI_to_SQL($_POST['dateDocFour']));
    $bonReceptionEntity->setfournisseur($_POST['fournisseur']);
    $bonReceptionEntity->setcode_doc_four($_POST['codeDocFour']);
    $bonReceptionEntity->settype_doc_four($_POST['typeDocFour']);
    $bonReceptionEntity->setdoc_four($nameFile);
    $bonReceptionEntity->setTOT_REMISE_L($_POST['TOT_REMISE_L']);
    $bonReceptionEntity->setPR_REM_P($_POST['PR_REM_P']);
    $bonReceptionEntity->setMT_REM_P($_POST['MT_REM_P']);
    $bonReceptionEntity->setTOT_HT_BRUT($_POST['TOT_HT_BRUT']);
    $bonReceptionEntity->setTOT_HT_NET3($_POST['TOT_HT_NET3']);
    $bonReceptionEntity->setTOT_HT_NET1($_POST['TOT_HT_NET1']);
    $bonReceptionEntity->setTOT_FODEC($_POST['TOT_FODEC']);
    $bonReceptionEntity->setTOT_HT_NET2($_POST['TOT_HT_NET2']);
    $bonReceptionEntity->setTOT_TVA($_POST['TOT_TVA']);
    $bonReceptionEntity->setD_TIMBRE($_POST['D_TIMBRE']);
    $bonReceptionEntity->setTOT_TTC($_POST['TOT_TTC']);
    $bonReceptionEntity->setetat($_POST['etat']);
    $bonReceptionEntity->setdescription('This is description');
    $lignesIdArt = array();
    $lignesCodeArt = array();
    $lignesDesArt = array();
    $lignesQteArt = array();
    $lignesPuhtArt = array();
    $lignesTvaArt = array();
    $lignesDpaArt = array();
    $puhtArtLigne = array();
    $qteLigne = array();
    $remiseLigne = array();
    $thtLigne = array();
    $tvaLigne = array();
    $fodecLigne = array();
    $ttcLigne = array();
    if(isset($_POST['idArt'])) $lignesIdArt = $_POST['idArt'];
    if(isset($_POST['codeArt'])) $lignesCodeArt = $_POST['codeArt'];
    if(isset($_POST['desArt'])) $lignesDesArt = $_POST['desArt'];
    if(isset($_POST['qteArt'])) $lignesQteArt = $_POST['qteArt'];
    if(isset($_POST['puhtArt'])) $lignesPuhtArt = $_POST['puhtArt'];
    if(isset($_POST['tvaArt'])) $lignesTvaArt = $_POST['tvaArt'];
    if(isset($_POST['dpaArt'])) $lignesDpaArt = $_POST['dpaArt'];
    if(isset($_POST['puhtLigne'])) $puhtArtLigne = $_POST['puhtLigne'];
    if(isset($_POST['qteLigne'])) $qteLigne = $_POST['qteLigne'];
    if(isset($_POST['remiseLigne'])) $remiseLigne = $_POST['remiseLigne'];
    if(isset($_POST['thtLigne'])) $thtLigne = $_POST['thtLigne'];
    if(isset($_POST['tvaLigne'])) $tvaLigne = $_POST['tvaLigne'];
    if(isset($_POST['idTvaLigne'])) $idTvaLigne = $_POST['idTvaLigne'];
    if(isset($_POST['fodecLigne'])) $fodecLigne = $_POST['fodecLigne'];
    if(isset($_POST['ttcLigne'])) $ttcLigne = $_POST['ttcLigne'];
    echo $bonReceptionManager->addNewBonReception(
            $bonReceptionEntity, $lignesIdArt, $lignesCodeArt, $lignesDesArt, $lignesQteArt, $lignesPuhtArt, $lignesTvaArt, 
            $puhtArtLigne, $qteLigne, $remiseLigne, $thtLigne, $tvaLigne, $fodecLigne, $ttcLigne, $lignesDpaArt );
```

Comment: please post the error you said in the internet

Comment: This is the displyed error on the alert ..... "Error Ajax : Error"  .... no more

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7019723/3484498 the arguments for the error callback are `function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)`. Can you log everything with `console.log(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)` ?

Comment: especially `errorThrown`